# Having trouble displaying a date X axis, How do I get all dates, not just where data points are plotted?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a chart to display values across time, but there aren't data points for each day. The chart is just displaying dates on the X axis where data points exist. I want each date to have a vertical line, and the day displayed below for every day in the range (unless overlapping).

I'm using chart.ja version 4.2.1

[image: Current chart]

**Extra Points :-)**

I would also know how to keep the dates from overlapping when a large range (lots of dates) is being plotted.

Lastly, is it possible to display the dates on three lines, where the top line is the day, the second line shows the month name (once) in the middle of the month, and the third line shows the year in the middle of the year.

Comment: If you are using time axes, have a look to the doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#ticks-source

Comment: For overlappng, have a look to the doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration and autoSkip otpions.

Comment: @user2057925 Thanks for the quick answer, and I found some of the info interesting. But I don't see how to get the dates between data. For instance, if the data point date are 1/22, 1/25. 1/26. 1/30. I want the dates shown on the x-axis: 1/22, 1/23, 1/24, 1/25, 1/26, 1/27, 1/28, 1/28, 1/30. Maybe a different, format for the dates, but you get the idea. I want to fill in the missing days. What am I missing?

Comment: I think we could set data.labels with all dates in sequence (not only the data) and then set ticks.source : 'labels' in the axis. The data of datasets should be an array of numbers, not data points {x:, y:}